# Porting a Python program to C

Tags: c++, python, c, json, urllib2

I would like to port a program which is using urllib and json (Python 3) to C. My question is which libraries exist to replace urllib and json in C and which are the best (easier, documented, fast)? If there are not good libraries in C I also accept C++

Thank you all.

Comment: What is the reason it needs to be C? If it is deployment, I believe there are other solutions.

Comment: Have you considered using Shed Skin http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/  or Cython http://cython.org?

Comment: Why not just use curl + python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JSON, [json.org](http://www.json.org/) has a list of implementations for a variety of languages, including C. Most of them should be fairly lightweight and fast.

To replace urllib, you probably want to look at [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).